# How to derive the following estimate from example 3.9 in Bruce Palka's textbook: $|\int_\beta\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz| \leq \frac{\pi(1-e^{-r})}{r}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration

The following inequality occurs in example 3.9 on p. 336 of Bruce P. Palka's *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory* (Springer, 1990).

Let $r\in(1,\infty)$, and define $\beta: [0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ to be the smooth path $\beta(t) := re^{it}$. Then
$$
\bigg|\int_\beta\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\bigg| \leq \frac{\pi(1-e^{-r})}{r}.\tag{*}
$$

I don't see why this inequality holds. The best upper bound I am able to derive is $\pi$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\int_\beta\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\bigg| &\leq \int_\beta\frac{|e^{iz}|}{|z|}\,|dz|\\ &= \frac{1}{r}\int_0^\pi\big|e^{ire^{it}}\big|\,|rie^{it}|\,dt\\
&= \int_0^\pi\big|e^{r(-\sin(t) + i\cos(t))}\big|\,dt\\
&= \int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)}\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^\pi 1\,dt\\
&= \pi.
\end{align*}
$$

Could you please show me how to derive $(*)$?

Comment: @user1046533 I think [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) would give in this case the upper bound $\frac{\pi}{r}$, which is not what I asked. However, in the context of Palka's example, this bound would actually work just as well, so thanks.

Comment: If one inspects the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma#Proof_of_Jordan's_lemma) of Jordan's lemma then one sees that they drop a $e^{-aR}$ term at the end. So this the same, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly derived
$$
I = \left|\int_\beta\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\right| \le \int_0^\pi  e^{-r \sin(t)} \, dt 
$$
which is
$$
= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2}  e^{-r \sin(t)} \, dt \, .
$$
On this interval we have  $\sin(t) \ge \frac 2 \pi t$ ([Jordan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality)), so that
$$
 I \le 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2rt/\pi} \, dt = \cdots = \frac{\pi}{r}(1 - e^{-r}) \, .
$$

Comment: Jordan's inequality was the missing ingredient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant elementary alternative to Jordan's estimate is discussed in this article:
A Simplification in Certain Contour Integrals
Harold P. Boas and Eduardo Friedman
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 84, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1977), pp. 467-468

Basically they show that if you integrate over a large **triangular loop** then all the bounding integrands can be evaluated exactly by elementary methods.

Additional discussion and historical information is available here:
[H. Boas article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04887.pdf)